# Использование proxy при отправке письма через smtp?

Tags: php, proxy, smtp

Всем привет!
Есть модуль отправки сообщений: PHP + SwiftMailer
Необходимо отправлять почту через публичные smtp (mail.ru, gmail.com и т.д.) используя логин/пароль от аккаунта, но при этом использовать proxy, а как это сделать не пойму, т.к. smtp является уже конечной точкой.

Т.е. схема такая: 
Скрипт -> Письмо -> Проксирование -> SMTP

P.S. Были мысли отправлять запросы на nginx, а оттуда уже проксировать на smtp, но как этого сделать не знаю...

Есть у кого решения данной проблемы? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вроде бы никто специально не занимался такими извращениями. Но какое-то решение всё-таки [выложено в трекере SwiftMail](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/94):

> Would be nice to support sending emails using SMTP over a SOCKS5
>   proxy, just as Thunderbird does:
>
> ...
>
> This would also allow for cases where you might want to use the
>   socks-funtionality of OpenSSH to easily tunnel an internal server to
>   the outside world to reach its mailserver (even as a temporary
>   solution maybe).
>
> A socks-URL can be: {socks4|socks5}://[user[:pass]@][host[:port]]